# How do I work on my Rails app in development mode, but push it in production mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, git, github

Simple question, I do all my work on my local at home computer and then I `git push` to my repo on github, and then on my Ubuntu Server I do a `git pull` to get the content, but this causes inconsistencies because it pulls in development mode which I always have to go in and change. Is there a way to make it so I can work in development mode but push it to the repo production mode? Thanks.

Comment: git doesn't have knowledge of the rails env.  are you talking about using different branches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a git problem.  Rails environments ('production', 'development', 'test') affect how the code runs, but the code isn't changed.

When you run `rails server` on your development machine, the application starts in `development` mode because that is the default for that command.

You probably aren't using the same command to host your site on WEBrick on your server, but rather using something like Phusion Passenger, which can (should) be configured to boot your application in Production mode.

If the environment is set correctly, the `config/environments/#[RAILS_ENV}.rb` file is correctly selected upon loading the app, and the correct database sources are selected from `config/database.yml`.

Answer (score 0):

Rails apps default to `development` unless you set the `RAILS_ENV` variable to `production`.  Git doesn't really factor in to this.  On your production machine, you'll want to set `RAILS_ENV`.

Where to do this depends on your production deployment environment, and how your server is configured.  Things like Passenger default to production mode, and configuring that depends on your server (Apache, nginx).  If you're manually starting the server from the command line (via `rails s thin` or something along those lines), then you can configure it in your shell's startup file (`.profile` or something similar, depending on your shell).  thin also optionally takes an environment argument like `-e production`.

If you provide more details on how your production environment works, you might get a more specific answer for where to set `RAILS_ENV`.